# Remove specific event

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

Suppose i have a component, inputType="text"  with id ="cmp";

In a js file ,

```
$("input[type='text']").bind('keypress', function(e) {
//Case 1
});
```

In my jsp file,

```
$("#cmp").keypress(function() {
  //Case 2
});
```

Now I need to remove only one keypress event.
Is it possible to remove the keypress event for id ="cmp" that is registered from js file.
But we should not not remove event that is registered from jsp file.

Note:
According to my requirement, I cannot change .js file.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `off` of jquery method to remove events [Jquery OFf](http://api.jquery.com/off/)

> The off() method removes event handlers that were attached with .on().
>   See the discussion of delegated and directly bound events on that page
>   for more information. Specific event handlers can be removed on
>   elements by providing combinations of event names, namespaces,
>   selectors, or handler function names. When multiple filtering
>   arguments are given, all of the arguments provided must match for the
>   event handler to be removed.

```
$('#cmp').off('keypress');
```

Answer (score 0):

use [off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/)

> off: Remove an event handler.

```
$('#cmp').off('keypress');
```

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use either [.unbind()](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) or [.off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/) (*jQuery 1.7+*) depending on how the event was originally attached and what version of jQuery you are using.

```
// Prior to jQuery 1.7
$("#cmp").unbind("keypress");

// jQuery 1.7+
$("#cmp").off("keypress");
```

If you can modify the original location where you are binding the event handler, you might also be able to use [event namespaces](http://api.jquery.com/on/#event-names) to remove only a specifically named event.

```
// Original binding
$("#cmp").on("keypress.someName", function() {
  ...
});

// Unbinding
$("#cmp").off("keypress.someName");
```

**[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/VGUUZ/1/)**